# reading infile to xcode

Tags: c++, xcode

how can i read from a file that i call data into the value x

i placed the file in the program file but keep given me

file not found..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

double const NUMB=10;



int main ()
{
double x;

  ifstream infile;
  infile.open("data");

  if (!infile.is_open()){
    cout<<"NOT OPEN"<<endl;
    system ("PAUSE");
    exit (1);
  }

  infile >>x;

  while (infile>0){
    cout<<x<<endl;
  infile>>x;
  }

  infile.close();
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: The code is fine, do you have a file called 'data'?

Comment: Hello, yes i have a file call data placed in the folder where main is located

Comment: That's isn't necessarily the right place. It all depends on your compiler/platform. Hard to give better advice without knowing how you are building and running your program.

Comment: i have xcode running on mac..

Comment: i used to have eclipse and i love it but once i update my system eclipse stop working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Xcode the file named "data" has to be placed in the build products directory. That is, it needs to go in the same place the executable is put by Xcode after building. By default this is not the directory where the source code is. The easiest way to handle this for command line applications like this is just to include the file "data" in your project and then tell Xcode to copy the file to the build products directory whenever it builds. You do this by clicking on the project and then the target you are building. At the top of the target settings go to the "Build Phases". The last phase should be "Copy Files". Click "+" in "Copy Files" and select your "data" file, which will be listed as long as you have added it to the project.